# Powershell Core: Loading Microsoft.Build

Tags: msbuild, gitlab, gitlab-ci, powershell-core, gitlab-ce

I'd like to enumerate all evaluated properties of an MSBuild project in a GitLab CI/CD script ( Alpine .NET Core SDK image).

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.Build")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Build")
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Build"

New-Object Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project($csproj)
```

However, none of the combinations above seem to locate the `Microsoft.Build` assembly and let me instantiate a `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` instance.

I assumed there had to be the Microsoft.Build assembly in the SDK image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this seems to do the trick.

```
$msbuild_asm = Get-ChildItem -Path / -File -Filter "Microsoft.Build.dll" `
                             -Recurse `
                             -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
             | Select-Object -Last 1
Add-Type -Path $msbuild_asm
```